# How can I color manually the bars within multiple facets of a ggplot2 graph, using a different color for each facet?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, facet

I've built a faceted graph in ggplot2, each facet representing an organization with 3 distinct measures (Competence, Experience and Values). I got the following output so far which is great, but I need to go one step further:

```
qplot(Trust.Bucket, Trust.Average, data = mydata, geom="bar", fill=Firm, facets = . ~ Firm)
q <- qplot(Trust.Bucket, Trust.Average, data = mydata, geom="bar", fill=Firm, facets = . ~ Firm)
q + scale_y_continuous(limit = c(0, 5)) + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-90))
```

It's basically filling all 3 bars (Competence, Experience and Values) from each facet/Organization with a distinct color. This is great, but what I need is to color each facet in the same way as above but using the brand colors of each organization indicated in the facets' headers (e.g. Amazon = "darkorange4", Apple = "grey49", Google = "springgreen3", etc). What do I miss from my code to achieve this result?

Thanks a lot in advance for helping.
[image]

Comment: `opts` was deprecated quite a long time ago, what version of `ggplot` are you using?

Comment: Also, edit the question to add some of your data to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manually setting group colors for ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180115/manually-setting-group-colors-for-ggplot2)