# ggplot label color category

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, label

I am working in ggplot and I would like to manually change the fill color of my labels according to a factor. There is a column called 'Gene' and it works when I use **fill=factor(Gene)** but I would like to chose my colors, since I have two graphs and now the "Genes" are colored differently in the two graphs.

My code looks like this:

```
dat<- read.delim("SCN.study_Pvariants_42.txt",sep="\t",check.names=F)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = dat$Index, y = as.numeric(dat$Parazscore))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "darkcyan") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title="SCN Paralog conservation",
       y="Parazscore",
       x="aminoacid sequence") +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=dat$'Variant',fill=factor(Gene)))
```

I changed it with using the **scale_color_manual** function and adding a vector **cols**:

```
dat<- read.delim("SCN.study_Pvariants_42.txt",sep="\t",check.names=F)
cols <- c("GENE1"="lightblue","GENE2"="green","GENE3"="yellow",etc)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = dat$Index, y = as.numeric(dat$Parazscore))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "darkcyan") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title="SCN Paralog conservation",
       y="Parazscore",
       x="aminoacid sequence") +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=dat$'Variant', fill=factor(Gene))) +
                         scale_color_manual(values=cols)
```

But regrettably, this does not work. 
Could someone help me to solve this?

Thank you, 
Anne

Comment: change it with `scale_fill_manual()` instead of `scale_color_manual()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually setting group colors for ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180115/manually-setting-group-colors-for-ggplot2)

Comment: Hi Riccardo, it does not work, it gives an error: non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: It worked! There was something wrong with the cols