# Manually set group colours based on values in global environment

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I have a a dataset and I want to set specific colours when using `ggplot`.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180115/manually-setting-group-colors-for-ggplot2) and can manually set the colours for values. However, I want to be able to set the colours based on a value that is from the global environment.

Example data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(place = c("City", "AAAAA", "ZZZZZ", "City", "AAAAA", "ZZZZZ", "City",
                 "AAAAA", "ZZZZZ"),
             x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1),
             y = c(0.475308283, 0.437369818, 0.204992979, 0.263934572,
                 0.671616954, 0.955005667, 0.048954328, 0.900494188,
                 0.418262936))
```

This works:

```
group_cols <- c("City" = "blue", "ZZZZZ" = "red", "AAAAA" = "green")

place2 <- "AAAAA"

df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(place %in% c("City", place2))

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, fill = place)) +
  geom_col() + scale_fill_manual(values=group_cols)
```

[image]

But I want to do this:

```
group_cols2 <- c("City" = "blue", place2 = "green")

place2 <- "AAAAA"

df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(place %in% c("City", place2))

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, fill = place)) +
  geom_col() + scale_fill_manual(values=group_cols2)
```

Using this - the 'place2' variable doesn't show up as filled. I have used 'AAAAA' and 'ZZZZZ' to represent that I can't colour by the order as it could sometimes come before 'City' and sometimes after it.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: would something like this work? `df2 %>%
  mutate(place = replace(place, place == place2, "place2")) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x, y, fill = place) +
  geom_col() + scale_fill_manual(values=group_cols2)`

Comment: It sort of does, it fills with the right colour, but the label is wrong, it is just 'place2' and when I change it, the colour disappears.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way but maybe  `df2 %>%
  mutate(place_new = replace(place, place == place2, "place2")) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x, y, fill = place_new) +
  geom_col() + scale_fill_manual(values=group_cols2, labels = df$place)` ?

Comment: That didn't work. The 'AAAAA' fill is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works

```
place2 <- "AAAAA"
group_cols2 <- c("City" = "blue", setNames("green",place2))



df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(place %in% c("City", place2))

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, fill = place)) +
  geom_col() + scale_fill_manual(values=group_cols2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `place2` object generated in `place2 <- 'AAAAA'` is something other than the `df2$place` level. Note that another transformation is necessary.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(place = c("City", "AAAAA", "ZZZZZ", "City", "AAAAA", "ZZZZZ", "City",
                       "AAAAA", "ZZZZZ"),
             x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1),
             y = c(0.475308283, 0.437369818, 0.204992979, 0.263934572,
                   0.671616954, 0.955005667, 0.048954328, 0.900494188,
                   0.418262936))
df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(place %in% c("City", place2)) 

levels(df2$place)
```

```
> levels(df2$place)
NULL
```

So:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(place %in% c("City", place2)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(place = as.factor(place))
df2
```

```
> df2
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  place     x      y
  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 City      1 0.475 
2 AAAAA     2 0.437 
3 City      4 0.264 
4 AAAAA     1 0.672 
5 City      3 0.0490
6 AAAAA     4 0.900
```

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, fill = place)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

```
group_cols2 <- c("City" = "blue", place2 = "green")
place2 <- "AAAAA"
ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, fill = place)) +
  geom_col() + scale_fill_manual(values=group_cols2)
```

[image]

To solve this, the two simplest ways are:

1. Change color scale, as you already did.

```
group_cols2 <- c("City" = "blue", "AAAAA" = "green")
ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, fill = place)) +
  geom_col() + scale_fill_manual(values=group_cols2)
```

[image]

2. Change info in the data frame.

```
group_cols2 <- c("City" = "blue", place2 = "green")
df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(place %in% c("City", place2)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(place = as.factor(place), 
                place = dplyr::case_when(place == "AAAAA" ~ "place2",
                                         place == "City" ~ "City"),
                place = forcats::fct_relevel(place, "place2"))

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, fill = place)) +
  geom_col() + scale_fill_manual(values=group_cols2)
```

[image]