# Set colors of Factors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to make two scatter plots with ggplot2, which will have different groupings, but I would like the colors of the factors/groups to stay the same in both plots. The code below produces different colors depending on the order.

```
type<-c("Aorta", "Aorta", "Coronary", "Coronary", "Pulmonary", "Vein", "Vein")
PC1<-sample(x=1:10, size = 7)
PC2<-sample(x=1:10, size = 7)
pca<-data.frame(type, PC1, PC2)
ggplot(pca, aes(x=PC1, y = PC2, color = pca$type)) + 
    geom_point(size=5)


type2<-c("Aorta", "Aorta", "Coronary", "Coronary", "Pulmonary", "Vein", "Vein", "Kidney", "Kidney", "Stomach", "Stomach")
PC1<-sample(x=1:20, size = 11)
PC2<-sample(x=1:20, size = 11)
pca2<-data.frame(type2, PC1, PC2)
ggplot(pca2, aes(x=pca2$PC1, y = pca2$PC2, col=pca2$type2)) + 
    geom_point(size=5)
```

I have attempted to do something similar to this suggestion ([Manually setting group colors for ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180115/manually-setting-group-colors-for-ggplot2)) , but am having some difficulty translating the bar in this exmaple to a scatter in my example.

Comment: Add `scale_color_discrete(limits = unique(c(type, type2)))` to both plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't label the colors manually then ggplot will use its default scheme, which changes as the number of factors changes. One option is to set up separate label schemes with equivalent colors for overlapping types:

```
library(tidyverse)

label_colors_4 <- c("Aorta" = "red", "Coronary" = "yellow", "Pulmonary" = "brown", "Vein" = "green")
label_colors_6 <- c(label_colors_4, "Kidney" = "blue", "Stomach" = "purple")

pca %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = type)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = label_colors_4)

pca2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = type2)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = label_colors_6)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, one (perhaps ignorant) question, is the piping required? I tried it without, and it seems to work, so I'm curious if there are pros/cons to using it or not. Thanks again!