# Single Color for a Continuous Variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am interested changing the size and colors of the line of the continuous variables (empathy; negative, activating emotions; positive, activating emotions; SDI total) to purple, red, yellow, and black, respectively.

How can I do this?

```
ggplot ()+
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=time, y=SDI_Mean))+
  geom_line(data=data, aes(x=time, y=SDI_Mean, col="SDI Total (Means)"))+
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=time, y=Empathy))+
  geom_line(data=data, aes(x=time, y=Empathy, col="Empathy"))+
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=time, y=Positive_Activating))+
  geom_line(data=data, aes(x=time, y=Positive_Activating, col="Positive, Activating Emotions"))+
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=time, y=Negative_Activating))+
  geom_line(data=data, aes(x=time, y=Negative_Activating, col="Negative, Activating Emotions"))+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(ID))+
    labs(x = "Discussion",
       y = "Variable Counts")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Try `+ scale_color_manual(values = c("purple", "red", "yellow", "black"))`

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180115/manually-setting-group-colors-for-ggplot2