# Change color of bars in one facet panel only

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-wrap

Below is a simple code for ggplot bar graph with facet_wrap:

```
categories <- c("category 1", "category 2", "category 3")
groups <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

df <- expand.grid(category = categories, group = groups)
df$value <- rnorm(12, 1, 0.5)

ggplot(df, aes(x = category,
               y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~ group)
```

Now I want the bars for the group C to be red (just for the group C). How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually setting group colors for ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180115/manually-setting-group-colors-for-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to the other question I linked. However, your comment indicated that the connection was not clear. The key is to realise that you are setting the color by `group`, but that you can set the color and also create facets by the same column.

Define your colors:

```r
colors  <- rep("grey50", length(unique(df$group)))  |>
    setNames(unique(df$group))
colors["C"]  <- "red"


# `colors` is a named vector that looks like this:
#           A        B        C        D 
#    "grey50" "grey50"    "red" "grey50"
```

Then draw the plot setting the [`fill`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_colour_fill_alpha.html) aesthetic to `group`, and use [`scale_fill_manual()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html) to specify the `colors` we defined:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(
    x = category,
    y = value
)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = group)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
    facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]